# How do I finger this? (Fast run with alternating octaves in same register.)

Tags: piano, fingering

I'm having trouble figuring out the fingerings for the following passage I transcribed myself. It comes from a piece called "神さびた古戦場(kamisabita kosenjou)　～ Suwa Foughten Field" from the game 東方１０ (Touhou 10).
The rests in bars 1 and 3 are place holders for bass notes which require a jump to and from the alternating octaves in bar 2. The octaves and the run can be considered two seperate voices, of which the octaves should be brought out.

The problem lies in the fact that the run goes right through the alternating octaves at high tempo. Should I just practice more and play each of both voices with one hand? If so, which hand should go over the other? Otherwise, how should I distribute them?

[image: sheet music]

single staff version:

[image: single staff sheet music]

Comment: I'd almost suggest playing the second note in the last bar with the left hand.

Comment: You do this by ignoring the implied assignment of notes to hands, and redistribute them as needed to obtain a useful hand position.  Unless this is an *etude* specifically for practicing extremely uncomfortable positions, this is a perfectly reasonable and valid solution.

Comment: Is the voice crossing a deliberate choice that must be maintained? When transcribing something like this for piano would it be acceptable to drop the left hand an octave lower?

Comment: It is, but it would be acceptable to lower the run by an octave as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

If you were in the position of having to play this live, I'd suggest two keyboards, one for the octaves, one for the run.   It's very unlikely it ever WAS played live, all at once, and certainly not by one player on one keyboard!

Comment: I'm actually arranging the piece for piano myself after hearing someone play it at a train station a while back. I couldn't help but think how cool it was, and that I wanted to do it myself. I'm confident this is exactly what was played too, since it's just a straight up reduction of the original.

Answer (score 0):

There are alternate octaves in both hands. The left hand ones you can only play as is, using pinky and thumb - whole hand movements. The third bar could be done the same (thumb and pinky), but another way is to use both hands, playing l/r/l/r/l/r/l/r. The music suggests strongly that this is *not* what's expected, but the end product may be easier to execute this way. It will also depend what's in the next bar. The way it comes over is usually more important than obeying the fingering etc.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but I feel you missed the point so I edited and clarified the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you could give me a version with the key letters maybe I could help you out? (like in the C D E F G A B format). I've been playing for 3 years (ish) but I dunno how to read staff.

Comment: [midi](https://onlinesequencer.net/567328)